# Error Installing Xamarin Tools VS2015 : A Setup Package is either missing or damaged Error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, mono

I am using Visual Studio 2015 . I have installed vs2015 from iso . VS2015 is installed . But Now i am going to installed xamarin tools for visual studio 2015 but when i started the package faced this error

I am downloading Xamarin Tools from here - https://www.xamarin.com/download

I have seen the stack overflow question here - ["A Setup Package is either missing or damaged" error while installing Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445763/a-setup-package-is-either-missing-or-damaged-error-while-installing-visual-stu)

It is said in question link that error is resolved 8 months ago it was error in setup . But it still exist

I am trying to install xamarin tools in vs 2015 got setup but it came with error above no xamarin / mobile apps tools installed if skip the error

What could be possible solution please?

Comment: try to install using administrative rights, and if doesn't work just download the full iso.

Comment: @bns , Sorry administrative rights don't work . Can you please tell me which iso and what product will be in that iso . i am already having vs 2015 iso and i already installed it

Comment: I meant the visual studio iso. Same thing happened to me while using the online installer, but using this iso https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409 instead It worked for me.

Comment: visual studio is already installed from iso i am just install xamarin tools for visual studio 2015 and got this error

Comment: what could be possible reason for this

Comment: for me it was something related with android SDK and Java SE development kit. So instead of taking the packages from xamarin installer I used the ones included in the VS iso.

Comment: i install vs from iso can you please elaborate in details please

Comment: Well, I had the same problem in windows 10. In windows 7 it worked.
What I did was to uninstall everything (yes, I know it takes a almost a day) and install VS community 2015 with update 2 again from the iso with administrative rights, checking that the options I needed for "Common Tools and Software Development Kits" in the section "Cross Platform Mobile Development" were selected, so it was VS and not the Xamarin Installer who installed them.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla - can you contact me off-list directly at eric.knox@microsoft.com so I can get setup logs from your machine? The issue you're describing is not a known problem, but I'm not fully clear on what you're installing and precisely which file is failing to download.

Comment: @EricKn , yes sure let me know when you can connect so I can ready to connect . thanks for that i am going to connect with you

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla - sorry for missing this. I was looking for you to email me. To collect setup logs, please download and run collect.exe from http://aka.ms/vscollect. When it finishes, I will need you to share %temp%\vslogs.zip with me via OneDrive, Dropbox or something like that. If you email me, I can give you a writable location to share that file, or you can tell me where I can find the file if you can host it.

Comment: ok thanks @Erickn I will sending you data very soon

Comment: @EricKn did you fix this issue? I have the same problem :(

Comment: @JeCuRo - yes, Hemmanshu's issue was an issue on his computer. It was not an issue on the Microsoft Download Center site. If you can run the same collection steps and share your local machine setup logs with me at my Microsoft email address above, I can take a look and see if I can understand why your machine failed too.

Comment: @EricKn thanks , I have just sent you the vslogs

Comment: In my case it was just a problem with the proxy . I have changed the Internet connection and all is working like a charm . Thanks a lot to @EricKn for his support