# Is There Any Xamarin Tools Offline Installer For Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

I Have Tried Installing Xamarin Tools For Visual Studio With Online Installer and Suffered From an Error . I have seen others also suffering from this error on question here -

[Error Installing Xamarin Tools VS2015 : A Setup Package is either missing or damaged Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146876/error-installing-xamarin-tools-vs2015-a-setup-package-is-either-missing-or-dam)

I want to ask Is there any Offline installer available. As after long time of online installation It gives Error as stated above

I have installed VS 2015 from ISO then downloaded the xamarin from xamarin.com/download and suffered from error that you can see in link I provided

Comment: I strongly want to know why Downvote . You can see issue on link i provided

Comment: I Strongly Recommend Please Try to provide comments for reasons why you are downvoting

Comment: @JonClements , Can you please tell me how this question is duplicate . It is quite different approach . I am just asking whether there is an alternative for online installer of VS Xamarin tools or not How can u relate it to that question

Answer (score 0):

Download the full iso of Visual Studio , and try to install it on  a clean computer .

Comment: What do you mean by clean computer ? Do you want to me to Uninstall Everything from my pc to make it clean if I am not having alternative computer . 

For your info I have installed VS 2015 from ISO then downloaded the xamarin from xamarin.com/download and suffered from error that you can see in link I provided

Comment: well maybe it is my approach , but I quite often format my computer to install the latest VS and i put my work in my backup storage to eliminate having problems because of other stuff installed . 
Anyway what I wanted to say is to download the latest VS 2015 with Update 2 . When you install it , choose Cross-platform . This will install Xamarin for you with all its integrations. No need to visit Xamarin.com