# SSIS VSTA Script Editor Not Displaying in VS2015

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, vsta

I recently created a new SSIS project from within VS2015.  I added a script task and when I click on the "Edit Script" button.  Visual Studio opens; however, there's no solution

I'm running VS as administrator.  I've tried re-installing Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015.  With no luck. I did once get the solution to pull up after I re-installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015; however, the next time I clicked "Edit Script" there was nothing.

Is this a bug withing VSTA or has anyone else came across this issue?

**"Edit Script" buttion from within the Script Component:**
[image]

**No solution when clicking "Edit Script":**
[image: No solution when clicking Edit Script]

Comment: what do you mean with 'there's no content'? maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: A bigger screenshot showing the entire gui.....

Comment: It seems if I do a repair on my Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 I can get the solution to show up 1 time. But a 2nd attempt brings VS with no solution.

Comment: That is odd! Try taking a copy of your project - detach it from source control and see if that is affecting it? Also - try creating a dummy project with a dummy script and see if you can open that? Temporarily disable anti-virus too...

Comment: I tried creating a brand new ssis project, dragging over a Script Task, and then clicking Edit Script.  Same results.

Comment: It seems like other people have had this issue. But generally doing the repair on MVST does the trick.  For example [link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2015/11/03/vsta-script-editor-not-displaying-in-vs2015-ssis-2016.aspx).  Doesn't seem to permanently fix mine however.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vsta+edit+script+ssis&oq=vsta+edit+script+ssis

Comment: I am trying to do this, using vs2017 version but can't seem to do it. Posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56037106/1257607)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, for me this problem was due to Resharper - if I go under Tools | Options | Resharper and Suspend Now it allows the VSTA editor to display each time.  Hope this helps

Comment: I do run Resharper and I could totally see it causing issues like this.  With that being said I'm unable to test at the moment as I ended up using the older version of VSTA  within VS 2013 as a work around.  I'll try to get to a point were I can install the newer version of VSTA and test this theory.  For now i"m going to mark this as the answer as I do think Resharper could cause this issue.  If my testing later on turns out to prove this wrong I'll update this post.

Comment: I was able to test this theory the other day.  I suspended ReSharper and still had no luck.

Comment: thank you sir, worked!

Answer (score 5):

I've solved the exact same problem today. In my case it was most likely  caused by installing and removing several versions of VS/SSDT without some proper clean-up.

Go to Control Panel -> Uninstall or change a program -> "Microsft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015" -> Change -> Repair.

Repeat the steps for "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015".

This should only fix your installation and not affect any of your projects.

After restarting my Windows the problem was fixed!

Comment: Ran repair on both and it didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

I have VS 2013 (with VSTA 2012) and VS 2015 (with VSTA 2015). I had the same problem: If I tried to edit a Script Task (both in VS 2013 SSIS or VS 2015 SSIS project), the VS 2015 shell opened, but was empty.

I tried the solution described by Rae: Uninstalling "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015" and subsequently repairing "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012". This solution worked for VS 2013, after that, all scripts are opened in VS 2012. But after that, in VS 2015 SSIS Projects, I could no longer edit Script Tasks. (Error message "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=14.0.0.0,...")

The solution was:
 - Repair "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015" (which re-installed VSTA 2015). After that I had the same problems like at the beginning, VS 2015 Shell opened empty, without source code file.
 - Install VS 2015 Update 3 (like recommended by Rob Nicholson). This was the fix...

After that, I can edit Script Tasks both in VS 2013 SSIS and VS 2015 SSIS projects, both open the VS 2015 shell.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue with an SSIS 2012 project.

**Uninstalling "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015" and subsequently repairing "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012" got it for me.**

My SSIS project in VS2012 would try opening scripts in a **VS2015** instance. After uninstalling VSTA 2015, VS2012 now successfully opens the scripts in a **VS2012** instance.

For reference, I have both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2015 installed. I also have SQL Server Data Tools v11.1 and v14.0 installed.

I'm guessing this issue comes down to clashing versions of Visual Studio Tools for Applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the proposed solution but could not get this working. After I updated SQL Data Tools to 14.0.61707.300 (the highest version of available for Visual Studio 2015 available) and applied Visual Studio Update 3 (14.0.25420.01) the code inside the Script Task / VstaProjects now populates correctly.  As a side note my SQL/SSIS version is 2016 and Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 is at 14.0.23829.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've encounted the same problem as well.

Since no solution to repair VisualStudio until now, I began to do the job by writting my own **code directly in the DTSX file**.

If your logic business was not very complex, this solution maybe suitable:

1. Firstly, **add a "Scritp Task"** in your package of SSIS project. It will generate lots of code in the DTSX file, and save our work.
2. **Open DTSX file** of the package in Notepad++/SublimeText, as your wish, and look for ***`"// TODO: Add your code here"`***, which was in a `public void Main()`.
3. Fun Coding!

I've uploaded a project of [TestScriptTask](https://github.com/ycaoyang/TestSSDT), in case of making coding easier in visual studio. It needs SQL Server Developer edition installed at least (Express edition probably would not work, didn't test).

Answer (score 0):

Restart VS 2015, then it will load the next time you try.
Every time it fails, restart VS.

Yes simple/tedious... but works. Just write everything correctly the first/1 time you edit the script ;) easy

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue and it was driving me crazy. GIT is definitely what is causing this. When you take the solution out of the source control directory, the problem disappears.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with git.  Moved my VS2015 solution out from git repository and VSTA 2015 will open once per user after a Repair of VSTA 2015.  Ran once for my id then quits working.  Ran VS 2015 then as Administrator and it worked only once that way before refusing to open.  Frustrating...

Comment: I also spun up a new project outside of source control for testing and had the same issues.