# Visual Studio 2017 SSDT add reference to script

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017, add-references-dialog

I am new using SSIS and want to create a script to connect to a Mongo DB, for this purpose I am trying to ***add a reference*** to a MongoDB driver as explained [here](https://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/)

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do so, in the solution explorer, there is no **Reference node**
[image]

Could you please point how to add a reference to my script in this project?
[image]

Comment: I have seen that there is an issue with this feature [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104379/ssis-script-task-edit-script-not-working.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different solutions I tried the following:

1. Uninstall SSDT and Reboot
2. Downloaded this version 15.8.2 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017)
3. Install SSDT selecting my version of Visual Studio
   [image]

and finally it worked:

[image: vs script]

Followed some of the steps explained [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104379/ssis-script-task-edit-script-not-working.html).