# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Community - offline installation failed - package is missing

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Community on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1

I do not have an internet connection on my machine.

I downloaded official image here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615448&clcid=0x409

During the installation I could skip some of packages, but I can not skip this vs_teamexplorercore

The same I have when trying to install Professional edition.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["A Setup Package is either missing or damaged" error while installing Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445763/a-setup-package-is-either-missing-or-damaged-error-while-installing-visual-stu)

Comment: Following the link the guy there can skip package, but I do not need to have some packages, for example I do not need to use Team Explorer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once with the so-called offline iso, to avoided the problem I worked as following:

Download Web Installer from Microsoft Web Site
Execute the Installer on another computer with internet connection, note that what you download is not the real VS installer but more like a web start/ wrapper.
Once you run it use Windows Task manager and find the real web installer path that is stored in your user temp folder
copy the real installer somewhere else. like C:\VS2015\
Open Command Prompt and execute the installer that you copied with this argument: /Layout .
Now installer will download the FULL offline installer to your selected folder! 
Zip the folder and bring it to your no-internet allowed server

Comment: Ok, I downloaded web installer from here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ for vs 2015 community. Run it, but in the task manager I see only this installer .exe process which. In %TEMP% I dont see any files too. Maybe I should finish the installation?
PS: I use virtual machine

Comment: Yes you need to start the installation or the task manager will show only the "web start/wrapper" The real installer is not in download, it will be in something like appdata\local\temp , eventually since a virtual machine can slow the response of screen update on task manager to be sure not miss it you can use Process Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to analize the file activity.